# Infinite two players zero sum game and Nash equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, infinite-games

Consider a two player zero sum game (finite strategy space) with mixed strategies. Let the game value is $v$ which is obtained at a Nash equilibrium say $(p,q)$ where $p$ and $p$ are probability law associated with the strategies of Player 1 and 2 respectively. Suppose there exist another pair of probability laws $(p_1,q_1)$ for which the game value is same as Nash Value $v$. Can we say that  $(p_1,q_1)$ is also a Nash equilibrium. Is this result also true for infinite game? That is if another set of strategies has same value as Nash equilibrium then that will also be a Nash equilibrium?

Comment: What do you mean by "game value" here?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Game value is the expected payoff.

Answer (score 1):

This can fail even in very simple finite games. Here, BR is a Nash equilibrium in pure strategies with a value of $0$. TL has the same value but is not a Nash equilibrium.

\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline  & L & R \\ \hline T & 0,0 & -1,1 \\ \hline B & 1,-1 & 0,0 \\ \hline  \end{array}

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification.